Can the first latent variable of a PLSR model explain less variation in either X or Y compared to the second latent variable?
I currently have a n x m dataset as the X block and a n x 1 dataset as the Y block. I am using the ROPLS package in R, and I've noticed that there are times when R2Y is greater in the second latent variable relative to the first. It is to my understanding that the first Latent Variable should always explain the most variance in the X Block first, even if that amount is minimal.
I ran two models, one is the basic PLSR model from ROPLS and the other is OPLSR (orthoganalized PLSR) from ROPLS as well on the same exact dataset with the same x and y. The X block has been standardized ($ {(x-\bar{x})}/\sigma$). The outputs of the PLSR model is below:
modelList_backup[[3]]@modelDF
    R2X    R2X(cum) R2Y    R2Y(cum) Q2   Q2(cum) Signif. Iter.
p1 0.615    0.615 0.219    0.219  0.192   0.192      R1     1
p2 0.085    0.700 0.238    0.457  0.181   0.338      R1     1

And the output of the OPLSR on the same exact dataset is below:
  modelList_visualization[[3]]@modelDF
     R2X   R2X(cum)  R2Y   R2Y(cum) Q2   Q2(cum) Signif.
p1  0.267    0.267 0.219    0.219 0.192   0.192      R1
o1  0.433    0.700 0.238    0.238 0.084   0.084      R1
sum    NA    0.700    NA    0.457    NA   0.276    <NA>

Given that this is PLSR and not PCA, I understand there is the added complexity of maximizing the covariation in both X and Y, instead of just maximizing the variation in X for each Latent Variable. Of course, the first model (modelList_backup) does show that R2X is greatest in the first LV, but the OPLSR version of it does not (as evidence by $p1_{R2X} < o1_{R2X}$). Moreover, both models show that the R2Y metric is greater in the second latent variable (p2 or o1 depending on PLSR or OPLSR models) and this detracts from my current understanding of what should occur. Could someone please help clarify this?
